# Transaction gets reverted when using send web3 function

Tags: web3js, contract-development, truffle-contract, revert

I have a basic smart contract that sets the hash of a string and retrieves it along with verification. The contract works perfectly fine, but the issue is with the .send method of web3 that reverts every time despite the absence of any modifiers or conditions. It will be great if anyone can suggest the solution.

Contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract VerifyHash{
   bytes32 hash;

   function setHash(string memory _value) public {
      hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_value));
   }

   function getHash()public view returns (bytes32){
       return hash;
   }

   function verifyHash(bytes32 _value)public view returns(bool){
      if(hash == _value)return true;
      else return false;
   }
}
```

Web3

```
const {Web3} = require("web3")
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
     'mnemonic',
    'http://localhost:7545')

 var VerifyHash = require("../abi/VerifyHashAbi") ;
 const web3 = new Web3(provider);
 (async() =>{

    try{
        let accounts =  await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        var verifyHash = new web3.eth.Contract(VerifyHash.abi,VerifyHash.address);
        //console.log(verifyHash.methods);
        const txReceipt = await verifyHash.methods.set('Not to reveal the number').send({from:accounts[0]});
        console.log("Transaction Hash:", txReceipt);
        var hash = await verifyHash.methods.get().call();
        console.log("Hash", hash);
        const hashFromWeb3 = web3.utils.keccak256("Not to reveal the number").toLowerCase();
        await verifyHash.methods.verifyHash(hashFromWeb3).call().then(result => {
            console.log(result);  
        });
     }
    catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
 })();
```

I am using ganache for testing.

Error:

```
Error: {
  jsonrpc: '2.0',
  id: 'c857a620-1acd-41c4-bded-b103cee9e334',
  error: {
    message: 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert',
    stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n' +
      '    at exactimate (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:182136)',
    code: -32000,
    name: 'RuntimeError',
    data: {
      hash: null,
      programCounter: 59,
      result: '0x',
      reason: null,
      message: 'revert'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

possible reason for the error is that you are using an incorrect gas limit or gas price for your transaction. You can try to adjust these parameters manually or use a service like EthGasStation to get the optimal values.
You can also use the estimateGas method of web3.js to get an estimate of the gas cost of your function call.

```
const gasEstimate = await 

    verifyHash.methods.set('Not to reveal the number').estimateGas({ from: accounts[0] });
```

Comment: I applied your solution but still the same, is there any possibility that something is missing in truffle config file .  const gasEstimate = await verifyHash.methods.set(encodedString).estimateGas({ from: accounts[0] });
        const tx = await verifyHash.methods.set(encodedString).send({ from: accounts[0], gas: gasEstimate });

Comment: Here is the error   Error: message: 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert',
    stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n' +
      '    at LegacyTransaction.fillFromResult (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:12745)\n' +
      '    at Miner.<anonymous> (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:36703)\n' +
      '    at async Miner.<anonymous>

Comment: (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:35116)\n' +
      '    at async Miner.mine (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:39680)\n' +
      '    at async Blockchain.mine (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:60063)\n' +
      '    at async Promise.all (index 0)\n' +

Comment: '    at async TransactionPool.emit (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\node_modules\\emittery\\index.js:303:3)',
    code: -32000,
    name: 'RuntimeError',
    data: {
      hash: '0xacd22b27d105d911edbed0473680f4e51bd55a4a679883fe58152bc1e149b63c',
      programCounter: 69,
      result: '0xacd22b27d105d911edbed0473680f4e51bd55a4a679883fe58152bc1e149b63c',
      reason: null,
      message: 'revert'

Answer (score 0):

I changed the web3 version from 4.1.2 to 1.3.6 and it worked